# Model validation not returning correct error message in Web API

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have a model (myModel) that has the following data annotation on myProperty

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "myProperty is required.")]
```

In the api controller we are validating the model as follows:

```
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{



   var errorResponse = new HttpRequestMessage()
.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadReques, ModelState);

    throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse);
}
```

What I get back in postman is:

```
    {
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": {
        "myModel": [
            "An error has occurred."
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to get back the error message from the data annotation.

Comment: cant you just put that in the response msg in your controller

Comment: throw new HttpResponseException(errorResponse); happens on that line number

Comment: That is not my objective here - I  want to have the mechanism return the message from the data annotation is the model

Comment: Hmm. Yeah dtata annotations display those messages in mvc using javascript validation if you want to send that message with your response Im pretty sure the only way to do it is include it in the response if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the error messages from the model state validation from the `ModelState.Errors` property, it's a collection of [ModelError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelerror(v=vs.118).aspx).

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.errors(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.ModelState.Errors)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried that but it only contains the default error "Required property 'myProperty' not found in JSON. Path '', line 23, position 1." and not the message defined in he data annotation.

Comment: Have you tried getting the `ErrorMessage` in one `ModelError` element in the `ModelState.Errors` collection?

Comment: Yes - I was looking at the collection that only had one items in it.

Comment: Ok, when you debug, in that only item you have, when you look in the property `ErrorMessage`, what value is in there?

Comment: The one I mentioned above Required property 'myProperty' not found in JSON. Path '', line 23, position 1.

Comment: This is weird, it seems to be a message of an error that happens before the validation is executed, I think it is not from a validation but from actual error.

Comment: No that is not it. the !ModelState.IsValid is trapping the error correctly and throwing the error - just not including the correct error message.

Comment: but it is an error with Line and position indication, this seems an error thrown from the code, not an error of validation. DataAnnotations validations don't throw exception.

Comment: That line number is where the error in the if(!ModelState.IsValid) is where the error gets thrown

Comment: That is not my objective here - I want to have the mechanism return the message from the data annotation that is the model

Comment: So that is it, it is an exception thrown from your code, it is not a Model.IsValid normal procedure, Model.IsValid shouldn't throw an error.

Comment: What I mean is, there is something else, that is not in the code you posted here that is causing the problem, the answer I gave should work for a Model.IsValid that works normally, you have to fix another code problem before you do it

Comment: One other thing that can be confusing is that MVC interprets this same error coming back correctly - only when I run the api from postman - and presumably from a consuming app that is not MVC do I not get the incorrect message.

Comment: So something is wrong with the parameters you are passing in the request

Comment: I think we are not on the same page here. In my request I am purposely leaving out a required parameter to get the modal validation to throw an error. I want this process the return the correct error message.

Comment: Try to do that with the field in it but with empty value, I don't think the [Required] annotation is to validate the existence of the field, but to validate if the field has a value. I know we are not in the same page, what you are telling me is that you need the ModelState.IsValid to do something that I am telling you that it can't do it like that.

Comment: OK - tried that and got the same result I did when I left it out completly

Comment: Did you do a request with a field `"myProperty": ""`in your object?

Comment: Tried it both ways. With myProperty in the request without a value and with myProperty not even included . Got the same error returned both ways

Comment: Sorry, but then I don't know, but I think that the problem is something before the call `ModelState.IsValid` that you are asking about in this post. I don't know how is your code, out of what you are asking in this post.

Answer (score 0):

For Example your model should like this

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[EmailAddress]
public string  EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

And your in your action method

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
    var error = ModelState.Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(e => new { Name = e.Key, Message = e.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage }).ToList();
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "ErrorList", error }
    });
}
```

Comment: You left out the ErrorMessage from the Required data annotation - something like this:  [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is the error I would like to see returned to postman")]

Comment: Thanks @Jim Evans for the correction, but to be humble, if I not set ErrorMessage then it will provide default message something like this

{    "ErrorList": [
        {
            "Name": "EmailAddress",
            "Message": "The EmailAddress field is required."
        }
        
    ]
}

Comment: I appreciate the information but my task is to get the data annotation error message returned. Thank you for the input though.